# How to model a class with multiple references to another class as a Core Data entity?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have the following structure that I am trying to model as Core Data entities. I am very new to Core Data and I can't seem to find a resource online to help me with this issue.

```
class ThingDetail {

   let color:  String
   let amount: Double
   let symbol: String

}

class Thing {
   let name: String
   let A: ThingDetail
   let B: ThingDetail
   let C: ThingDetail
   let D: ThingDetail

   init() {
       ...
   }

}
```

I made an entity for Thing and an entity for ThingDetail, but what do I do with properties A,B,C,D? It's not really a one-to-many relationship because I only want 4 references to ThingDetail. If I use a one-to-many relationship from Thing to ThingDetail named "thingDetails", then I'm assuming I'm going to get some set back that I would have to access as

```
thingDetails[0].color
thingDetails[1].symbol
etc...
```

but this doesn't seem right. Is this the way it has to be? I am unsure how to model these two classes as Core Data entities given these class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now, it's not a one-to-many relationship, it's four separate one-to-one relationships. That's OK, two entities may have more than one one-to-one relationship if it makes sense. If `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are meaningful names, then use those names and use four relationships.

If those names aren't meaningful though-- that is, `Thing` has four details but all that matters is getting all of them-- go with a one-to-many relationship. `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` don't seem especially meaningful but maybe they are, or maybe those are placeholder names and not the ones in your app.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I didn't really consider multiple one-to-one relationships for some reason, I think this is what I need. Quick question, do I need to handle an inverse relationship for this? ThingDetail doesn't really need to know about Thing.

Comment: Yes, at least until you become an expert at Core Data, and maybe not then. Relationships without inverses are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Would it be just those 4 relationships inversed?

Comment: A `Thing` must have 4 `ThingDetail`s, but a `ThingDetail` doesn't necessarily need to have strictly 4 `Things` (aka the inverse). A `ThingDetail `could reference any number of `Thing`s (one to many). So the inverse doesn't really make sense here. Sorry for kind of veering off but I'm not sure how to handle this. A similar scenario would be a `Location` might have 4 `Home`s, but a `Home` doesn't have 4 `Location`s (inverse). How is this handled?

Comment: I justed added 4 relationships from ThingDetail to Thing and made them one-to-many, I won't end up using them but it solves the warning

Comment: Inverse relationships are good to help Core Data maintain data integrity, but you're right that this sometimes means you add inverses you'll never use.